# QGIS3 weed tracking via polygon attributes

Tags: qgis, polygon, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute

I have been requested to provide some information about weed distribution on a site in the form of polygons that describe land forms. I am using QGIS3 and slowly getting the hang of it, might be too slow though. I expect someone would like to be able to filter the polygons to see the distribution of weeds at a later date. So when a weed is right for treatment they can just run a map and give it to a subcontractor to guide them where that weed needs treatment. I thought I could achieve this by creating an attributes table for the polygons.
I am not sure if a single attribute can handle multiple discreet values i.e species of weeds. Is there a better way of doing this?

I.E.

Polygon 1
Attribute: Weeds Present in area
Variables: Fleabane, fire weed, stinking roger, lantana

Polygon 2
Attribute: Weeds Present in area
Variables: Fleabane, fire weed, inkweed

Polygon 3
Attribute: Weeds Present in area
Variables: Fleabane, fire weed, inkweed

In this way if they wanted only to see info about the polygons containing Lantana only polygon 1 would be selected / visible / highlighted. Whereas if you queried which polygons had ink weed polygon 2 and 3 would be highlighted.